# How do I put condition in MAX in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to group my data by Date and then find max "Value" for different "Codes". How can I do this - I would like to supply a condition to `MAX()` but I don't think that is possible.

Columns:

```
Date: date
Time: time
Value: float
Code: varchar

SELECT MAX([Value] where [Code]='GOLD') AS BestGold, 
       MAX([Value] where [Code]='SILVER') AS BestSilver
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY [Date]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inline `iif`:

```
SELECT MAX(IIF([Code]='GOLD', [Value], null)) AS BestGold, 
       MAX(IIF([Code]='SILVER', [Value], null)) as BestSilver
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY [Date]
```

or `case`:

```
SELECT MAX(case [Code] when 'GOLD' then [Value] end) AS BestGold, 
       MAX(case [Code] when 'SILVER' then [Value] end) as BestSilver
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY [Date]
```

Comment: Do you think one of these if faster?

Comment: I don't think so, though I have not made a research.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Code]='GOLD'   THEN ['Value'] END) AS BestGold,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Code]='SILVER' THEN ['Value'] END) AS BestSilver
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY [Date];
```

The idea here is that the `MAX` function will only consider values of records for each respective type of code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use this

```
SELECT 
    [Date],
    [Code],
    MAX([Value]) AS Best
FROM [MyTable]
    where cODE IN ('GOLD','SILVER')
GROUP BY [Date]
```

If you want it as Separate Column, Then try Pivoting the same

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
       [Date],
       [Code],
       MAX([Value]) AS Best
    FROM [MyTable]
       where cODE IN ('GOLD','SILVER')
    GROUP BY [Date]
)
SELECT
    [Date],
    BestGold = [GOLD],
    BestSilver = [Silver]
    FROM CTE
    PIVOT
    (
       MAX(Best)
       FOR
       Code IN
       (
          [GOLD],[SILVER]
       )
    )P
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you require something like the below :-

```
DECLARE @TestCodes Table
(
 Date date,
 Time time,
 Value float,
 Code varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @TestCodes
VALUES
('2017-08-09','12:00',19900,'Gold'),
('2017-08-09','12:00',15001,'Gold'),
('2017-08-09','12:00',2500,'Gold'),
('2017-08-09','12:00',1200.01,'Metal'),
('2017-08-09','12:00',1900,'Metal'),
('2017-08-09','12:00',1800.1,'Silver'),
('2017-08-09','12:00',1100.01,'Silver'),
('2017-08-09','12:00',100.11,'Silver')

SELECT Date,Code,Max(value) AS MAXPriceOnAnyDate
FROM @TestCodes
GROUP BY [Date],CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `case`;

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code='GOLD'   THEN [VALUE] ELSE -1 END) AS BestGold,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code='SILVER' THEN [VALUE] ELSE -1 END) AS BestSilver
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY [Date];
```